# Algorithm for subgraph combinations search

Tags: algorithm, graph

With this undirected graph

[image: undirect graph]

In this graph I have different nodes with following types [A,B,C,D,E]. 
It means that is possible to exists different nodes with same type

Now imagine you have a set of node types [A,B,E]. You don´t know which node are those given nodes in the graph, only thing you know is the type of each node.

What you have to do is to find a best fit for that given set of nodes. 
Node has to be connected to each other

I´ve been testing an algorithm which consists in steps below:

1. Convert the graph to a linked list
2. Generate all possible combinations between all nodes considering those given types and how many times a node type appears. The given example is [A,B,E] but it could be other set such as [A,B,C,A]. 
   Some of possible (not all) combinations for [A,B,E] are: [image: combinations]
3. Check if nodes in those combinations are connected to each other
4. the best fit is the first combination where all nodes are connected.

The problem is number of nodes in the given graph. For small sets of nodes and small graphs the algorthim is ok. But when the number of nodes are increased I have a thousands of possible combinations and those combinations consume a lot of memory.

I`ve been searching for some algorithm which could be able to solve this problem efficiently with low cost memory.

I have spent days reading and testing all kind of algorithm and until now I couldn`t find a better solution.

Suggestions are very appreciated

Comment: hint: get some graph drawing software. it will quickly save you hours of time. People swear by either IPE or yed.

Comment: yes, I just wanted to point out that drawing these graphs by hand in something like paint, ms powerpoint etc takes much longer than just downloading something that helps you draw graphs quickly.
There's quite some graph drawing libraries. Have a look at graphViz.

Answer (score 3):

This is called the Graph Motif problem and unfortunately it's NP-hard, even when the graph is a tree with maximum degree 3: see Theorem 1 in https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~hermelin/Conference%20Publications/Connected%20Motifs.pdf

This means it's very unlikely that any polynomial-time algorithm exists that can solve this problem.